# Как изменить версию mysql в Vagrant?

Tags: mysql, vagrant

Всем привет!
Не могу найти информацию о том, как изменить версию mysql c 5.7 на 5.6 в Vagrant.
Не уверен, что это можно сделать, но если кто-то знает как это сделать - напишите здесь, пожалуйста.
Спасибо!